# s3fs: AWS Message: Access Denied Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, s3fs

i installe s3fs as it is described here http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/InstallationNotes

then in i create user bucket_user

then put his accessKeyId:secretAccessKey in /etc/passwd-s3fs

them is S3 i create a bucket super_bucket

and set its policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddCanned",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::234234234234:user/bucket_user"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::super_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

then on my server /usr/bin/s3fs super_bucket /mnt/s3/

and recieve answer:

```
s3fs: CURLE_HTTP_RETURNED_ERROR

s3fs: HTTP Error Code: 403

s3fs: AWS Error Code: AccessDenied

s3fs: AWS Message: Access Denied
```

Version of s3fs being used (s3fs --version): 1.61

Version of fuse being used (pkg-config --modversion fuse): 2.8.4

System information (uname -a): Linux Ubuntu-1110-oneiric-64-minimal 3.0.0-14-server #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 21 20:49:05 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Distro (cat /etc/issue): Ubuntu 11.10 \n \l

s3fs syslog messages (grep s3fs /var/log/syslog): empty

**so i start from the begining**

on server

nano ~/.passwd-s3fs

cmd+v accessKeyId:secretAccessKey

chmod 600 ~/.passwd-s3fs

in bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::super_bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::super_bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

"save"

/usr/bin/s3fs super_bucket /mnt/s3/

and again receive

s3fs: AWS Message: Access Denied

Answer (score 6, accepted):

and no one said that i need to set User Policy in AWS IAM

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

### Analysis

Apparently [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) has issues regarding IAM support up to and including the most recent *stable* version 1.61 you are using, please review [IAM user permissions issue](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/issues/detail?id=153) for details, specifically [comment 4](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/issues/detail?id=153#c4):

> Evidently there is a call to [[ListAllMyBuckets()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPListAllMyBuckets.html)]
> that is required to determine if the bucket requested exists before
> attempting to mount.

Now, *ListAllMyBuckets()* is an [operation on the service](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPServiceOps.html) rather than a [bucket](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPBucketsOps.html) or an [object](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPObjectsOps.html), which are the only entities your `Resource` statement currently targets, thus using *ListAllMyBuckets()* is effectively denied by your current policy.

### Solution

As outlined in [comment 4](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/issues/detail?id=153#c4) as well, you must add an additional policy fragment to address this requirement for your version of *s3fs* accordingly:

```
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    }
]
```

Alternatively you could build s3fs version 1.61 from source after applying the patch provided in [comment 9](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/issues/detail?id=153#c9), which is supposedly addressing the issue (I haven't tested the patch myself though). Obviously a later version *might* include a fix for this as well, see [comment 11 ff](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/issues/detail?id=153#c11).

Good luck!

---

Given the intended functionality (i.e. *Mount a bucket as a local file system read/write*), [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) presumably requires access to the bucket itself as well, not only the objects contained therein, which is handled separately - try to replace your `Resource` statement with the following:

```
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::super_bucket",
    "arn:aws:s3:::super_bucket/*",
]
```

The first resource targets the bucket, while the latter targets the object contained therein.

Comment: and no changes if i make this
`
"Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
`

Comment: @fullpipe - yo, ruling out `Principal` like so as well has been a good idea indeed. You are probably aware already of the [IAM user permissions issue](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/issues/detail?id=153)? If not, you might want to check out [comment 1](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/issues/detail?id=153#c1), in particular the apparent requirement regarding file system permissions on `${HOME}/.passwd-s3fs`.

Comment: maybe you have some test bucket witch i could try to mount

Comment: @fullpipe: See my updated answer for further analysis of the [IAM user permissions issue](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/issues/detail?id=153) and resulting possible solutions for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by specifying `ListBucket` permissions on the bucket itself, and `Put/Get/DeleteObject` permissions on the *bucket contents*. I was following [this CloudAcademy guide](https://cloudacademy.com/blog/s3-ftp-server/) by way of the shell script in [this repo](https://github.com/cloudacademy/s3ftp) that attempts to package it nicely. This is the working policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::super_bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::super_bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Prior to defining it this way, I had a bunch of permissions just on the bucket and not its contents, and while I was able to log in to my FTP instance, when I attempted `put test.txt`, I got a `553 Could not create file.` message.

I saw this in the logs during the failed `put` attempts. It was debug output from this debug command:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/s3fs super_bucket \
-o use_cache=/tmp,iam_role="super_ftp_user",allow_other /home/super_ftp_user/ftp/files \
-o dbglevel=info -f \
-o curldbg \
-o url="https://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com" \
-o nonempty
```

Output:

```
[CURL DBG] * Connection #8 to host super_bucket.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com left intact
[INF]       curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2267): HTTP response code 200
[INF]     s3fs.cpp:create_file_object(918): [path=/test.txt][mode=100644]
[INF]       curl.cpp:PutRequest(3127): [tpath=/test.txt]
[INF]       curl.cpp:PutRequest(3145): create zero byte file object.
[INF]       curl_util.cpp:prepare_url(250): URL is https://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/super_bucket/test.txt
[INF]       curl_util.cpp:prepare_url(283): URL changed is https://super_bucket.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test.txt
[INF]       curl.cpp:PutRequest(3225): uploading... [path=/test.txt][fd=-1][size=0]
[INF]       curl.cpp:insertV4Headers(2598): computing signature [PUT] [/test.txt] [] []
[INF]       curl_util.cpp:url_to_host(327): url is https://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[CURL DBG] * Found bundle for host super_bucket.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com: 0x7fa0d00d3c60 [can pipeline]
[CURL DBG] * Re-using existing connection! (#8) with host super_bucket.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[CURL DBG] * Connected to super_bucket.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com (123.456.789.012) port 443 (#8)
[CURL DBG] > PUT /test.txt HTTP/1.1
[CURL DBG] > Host: super_bucket.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[CURL DBG] > User-Agent: s3fs/1.88 (commit hash ***; OpenSSL)
[CURL DBG] > Accept: */*
[CURL DBG] > Authorization: xxxxxxx
[CURL DBG] > Content-Type: application/octet-stream
...
[CURL DBG] > Content-Length: 0
[CURL DBG] >
[CURL DBG] < HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
[CURL DBG] < x-amz-request-id: 1234567890
[CURL DBG] < x-amz-id-2: ******
[CURL DBG] < Content-Type: application/xml
[CURL DBG] < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[CURL DBG] < Date: Tue, 19 Jan 2021 04:30:15 GMT
[CURL DBG] < Server: AmazonS3
[CURL DBG] * HTTP error before end of send, keep sending
[CURL DBG] <
[CURL DBG] * Connection #8 to host super_bucket.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com left intact
[ERR] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2287): HTTP response code 403, returning EPERM. Body Text: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>1234567890</RequestId><HostId>***</HostId></Error>
[INF]       cache.cpp:DelStat(578): delete stat cache entry[path=/test.txt]
```